# MVC - converting to unobtrusive jquery in a grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Below is an editor template that works, but needs to be improved.
Specifically the checkbox has an onclick event with call a javascript function;

AdministratorFlagClickFunc(employeeId)

What I should do instead is specify a click() event in the script. However how do I do this given the template is part of a grid and I need to identify the id of the checkbox on every row, plus the associated parameter?

```
@model UserLineViewModel
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Employee.Forename)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Employee.Surname)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.UserScd.Created)
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.UserScd.AdminFlag,
                    new { id = "checkBoxAdministratorFlag", 
                        onclick = "AdministratorFlagClickFunc(" + Model.UserScd.EmployeeId + ")" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Remove", "Delete", new { id=Model.UserScd.EmployeeId  }, new AjaxOptions()
                { 
                    OnSuccess="refreshPostback"   
                    , Confirm="Are you sure that you want to remove this person?"
                    , HttpMethod = "post"
                })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you want to move the click handler out of the markup and into script?  You could attach the handler via css class (not id as those should be unique per page) and get the emp id via a hidden element:

markup:

```
<td style="text-align: center;">@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.UserScd.AdminFlag, new { class = "checkBoxAdministratorFlag"})@Html.HiddenFor(Model.UserScd.EmployeeId) </td>
```

script:

```
$('.checkboxAdministratorFlag').click(function() {

    var empId = $(this).next('input').val();
    //....

});
```